# pynput keyboard.press() causing system to hitch

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I'm trying to use the pynput module to create a keymapping tool for my Logitech G600. Software exists for this on Windows, but not for Linux. When I get to the point where I want to call the proper mapped key, my whole system hitches for a second or so. Not knowing much about the problem (or threading) I decided to stick the keyboard.press() call into a thread in the hopes that hitch would localize itself to the thread rather than the system (or something). Yes, I need to learn more about threading. For now, though, is there an easy fix for the hitching or is this simply inherent to the pynput module?

Python == 3.8.5, Pynput == 1.7.3

The code in question:

```
if button == 79:
    print("G9 clicked!")
    x = threading.Thread(target=send_key, args=(Key.esc,), daemon=True)
    x.start()
```

Calls the function:

```
def send_key(_key):
    global keyboard

    print("Thread run")
    keyboard.press(_key)
    keyboard.release(_key)
```

EDIT: Interestingly, swapping the pynput/threading calls for simply "subprocess.call('xdotool key Escape', shell=True)" or its "os.system(command)" equivalent resulted in the same hitching issue.

If it helps, I'm reading in from the mouse's location at "/dev/input/by_id/...mouse_file...". Though I'm fairly certain that the error is due to the above code, here's the entirety of the code if it's useful:

```
import os
import struct
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import threading


keyboard = Controller()

def get_mouse(_path, _file_start, _file_end):

    files = os.listdir(_path)
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(_file_start) and file.endswith(_file_end):
            return _path + file

def send_key(_key):
    global keyboard

    print("Thread run")
    keyboard.press(_key)
    keyboard.release(_key)

path = "/dev/input/by-id/"
file_start = "usb-Logitech_Gaming_Mouse_G600_"
file_end = "-if01-event-kbd"
file = get_mouse(path, file_start, file_end)

with open(file, 'rb') as mouse_events:
    while True:
        events = mouse_events.read(3)
        button, x, y = struct.unpack('3b', events)
        release = False
        if button == 79:
            print("G9 clicked!")
            x = threading.Thread(target=send_key, args=(Key.esc,), daemon=True)
            x.start()
        if button == 80:
            print("G10 clicked!")
        if button == 81:
            print("G11 clicked!")
        if button == 75:
            print("G12 clicked!")
            x = threading.Thread(target=send_key, args=(Key.f5,), daemon=True)
            x.start()
        if button == 76:
            print("G13 clicked!")
        if button == 77:
            print("G14 clicked!")
        if button == 71:
            print("G15 clicked!")
        if button == 72:
            print("G16 clicked!")
        if button == 73:
            print("G17 clicked!")
        if button == 82:
            print("G18 clicked!")
        if button == 74:
            print("G19 clicked!")
        if button == 78:
            print("G20 clicked!")
```

Comment: Why are you using /dev/input instead of pynput.mouse.Listener to listen for mouse events?

Comment: I wanted to avoid remapping my actual keyboard and simply remap the small number pad on the side of the G600. As far as I'm aware, pynput treats the numbers on a real keyboard the same as it treats the number pad on the side of the mouse. This would mean that if I listened for a mouse button's default setting (for example, the '1' key), it would also respond to when I would click the same key on the keyboard. I'd like to avoid that.